# what pronunciation marking is this?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

I saw the parenthesized material in a verbal book.

> 1. VANGUARD (VAN-gahrd)
> 2. ADEPT (uh-DEPT)
> 3. SATURATED (SACH-uh-RAY-tid)

I guess the material belongs to a type of marking for pronunciation. Can anyone tell me how to understand this type of marking? Thank you.

Comment: It's a kind of ["eye-dialect"](https://www.thoughtco.com/eye-dialect-spelling-term-1690700#:~:text=Eye%20dialect%20is%20the%20representation,Dialect%20Writing%22%20(1926).) for popular use (as opposed to IPA, as used by linguists and such). With your examples, they're also using CAPITALS to indicate "stressed" syllables (given more emphasis, enunciated more forcefully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VANGUARD (VAN-gahrd)
> ADEPT (uh-DEPT)
> SATURATED (SACH-uh-RAY-tid)

The parenthesised sequences of alphabet are called the '[phonetic spellings](https://www.dictionary.com/e/phonetic-spelling/)' of the words. It shows how you would pronounce a particular word. The capitalised parts are the 'stressed' syllables of the words. '[Stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics))' (or 'accent') is relative emphasis or prominence given to a certain syllable in a word i.e. that syllable is the strong syllable in the word. For example, the first syllable in the word 'English' is stressed—*ING-glish*.

Comment: But of course the word ***adept*** can be either a noun or an adjective - and like so many English words, which part of speech the word represents ***depends on which syllable gets the stress***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: That's an important point! However, I explained the example provided by the OP.

Comment: Well, there's a bit of a chicken-and-egg issue here. If the example is supposed to help people understand what "eye-dialect" means, it's not exactly helpful to illustrate it with the word ***adept*** (which could be either **noun = /ˈadɛpt/** or **adjective = /əˈdɛpt,ˈ**, unless and until you understand how the eye-dialect rendition disambiguates).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: Is it better now? I don't know phonetic spelling

Comment: Oh! I didn't mean to pressure you into changing your actual answer text (which I thought was fine, so I upvoted as soon as I read it). Just remarking that ***adept*** probably wasn't the best choice for an "illustrative" word in OP's (TEFL?) book. But yeah - there's no mistaking where the stress goes in ***INglish*** (but I'm in two minds as to whether the capitalised part should include ***G*** - I don't know eye-dialect any more than I know IPA! :)